# How to open a list of buffers in Vim without affecting the current window

Tags: php, vim

In Vim, I would like to load a list of buffers without affecting the current window.

I currently load a list of buffers doing

```
:n **/*.php
```

It works very well aside changing my current window to the last file that got loaded. I'm looking for a specific solution where the buffers are loaded in the background and my current window is not affected.

I am *not* after:

1. How to get my previous window back like:

   ```
   :b #
   ```
2. How to create a Vim function to avoid losing my window.
3. How to create a session and load it back

   ```
   :mksession myproject.vim

   # vim -S myproject
   ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For those voting to close the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clear the argument list and add files using `:argadd`:

```
:sil! argd * | arga **/*.php
```

Here all files are deleted from the argument list first by the
`:argdelete` command (since any filename matches the `*` file-pattern
in Vim). The deletion command is run under the `:silent!` command to
suppress displaying the E480 error when the argument list is already
empty. After that, any files to be added to the argument list can be
appended to it using the `:argadd` command.